# AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Transpose'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

***i m trying to use pillow to make transpose for the image***

```
    # To use 90 Degrees Rotation, use:
    #rot_90 = pic.transpose(Image.Transpose.ROTATE_90)
    
    # Horizontal Flip with New File Names
    hoz_flip = pic.transpose(Image.Transpose.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    hoz_flip = hoz_flip.save(dest_path + "flr_" + str(hf) + ".jpg")
    hf += 1
    
    # Vertical Flipping with New File Names
    ver_flip = pic.transpose(Image.Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
    ver_flip = ver_flip.save(dest_path + "ftb_" + str(vf) + ".jpg")
    vf += 1
```

Comment: Make sure Pillow is up to date `pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen it worked well after the Pillow upgrade ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your version of Pillow you can add the following in:

```
import PIL.Image    
if not hasattr(PIL.Image, 'Transpose'):  
    PIL.Image.Transpose = PIL.Image
```

This will ensure that attribute is recognized even if it was not there previously.